# Theme loosing some images when moving to new server

Tags: media, migration

This is driving me up the wall! I'm using the "**Migrate DB**" plugin to export the DB for the new server. I have a double change as in we are moving server, and also domain.

http://thebodywisegym.co.uk -> https://bodywisegym.co.uk

So I've told it to replace:

[image]

When I put that on the new server's DB, the site *does* work for the most part - but **some** images are missing:

[image]

I can see the media in question in the "Media" part of the admin panel, so I know the image is fine. However, if I look at the source code on the site I get:

```
<img  class="alignleft" src="" alt="Testimonial" title="Ryan Anderson"/>
```

I'm sure I'm doing everything right! Have I missed something? I always seem to have fun and games moving sites from `http` to `https` and a new path :/

**UPDATE:**  As requested, I've tried to follow the code - its a bit of a hole!

This is the code in the template that is outputting the image:

```
                                    <?php mo_thumbnail(array(
                                        'before_html' => '<p>',
                                        'after_html' => '</p>',
                                        'image_size' => 'square',
                                        'image_class' => 'alignleft',
                                        'wrapper' => false,
                                        'image_alt' => 'Testimonial',
                                        'size' => 'full'
                                    )); ?>
```

That function then leads onto:

```
function mo_thumbnail($args) {

        $thumbnail_element = mo_get_thumbnail($args);

        if (!empty($thumbnail_element)) {
            echo $thumbnail_element;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

...and that follows into this function:

```
function mo_get_thumbnail($args) {
    global $mo_theme;

    $context = $mo_theme->get_context('loop');

    $defaults = array(
        'format' => 'array',
        'size' => 'full',
        'image_scan' => false,
        'youtube_scan' => false,
        'wrapper' => true,
        'show_image_info' => false,
        'before_html' => '',
        'after_html' => '',
        'image_class' => 'thumbnail',
        'image_alt' => '',
        'image_title' => '',
        'meta_key' => array(),
        'style_size' => false,
        'the_post_thumbnail' => true,
        // Keep this true to enable featured posts
        'force_aqua_resizer' => true,
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'cache' => false,
        // WordPress handles image caching for you.
    );
    $args = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);


    /* Extract the array to allow easy use of variables. */
    extract($args);

    $output = '';

    if (empty($image_size)) {
        $thumbnail_urls = mo_get_original_image_urls($args);
    }
    else {
        //image_size can be an array with height and width key value pairs or a string
        if (is_string($image_size)) {
            $image_size = mo_get_image_size_array($image_size);
            $args['force_aqua_resizer'] = false; // we have the wp sizes taken care of
        }
        $args['height'] = $image_size['height'];
        $args['width'] = $image_size['width'];
        $thumbnail_urls = mo_get_thumbnail_urls($args);
    }

    //create the thumbnail
    if (!empty($thumbnail_urls)) {


        $thumbnail_src = $thumbnail_urls[0];
        $thumbnail_element = $thumbnail_urls[1];

        if (empty($post_id))
            $post_id = get_the_ID();

        $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);
        $post_link = get_permalink($post_id);
        $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
        $rel_attribute = 'rel="prettyPhoto[' . $context . ']" ';

        if ($post_type === 'gallery_item') {
            // Make the anchor to gallery thumbnail point to the image directly
            $before_html = '<a title="' . $post_title . '" href="' . $thumbnail_src . ' ">';
            $after_html = '</a>' . $after_html;
            if ($wrapper) {
                $wrapper_html = '<div class="image-area">';
                $before_html = $wrapper_html . $before_html;
                if (mo_show_image_info($context) || $show_image_info) {
                    $image_info = '<div class="image-overlay"></div>';
                    $image_info .= '<div class="image-info">';
                    $image_info .= '<div class="post-title">' . $post_title . '</div>'; // do not link to post for gallery
                    $image_info .= mo_get_taxonomy_info($taxonomy);
                    $image_info .= '<div class="image-info-buttons">'; // Make this part of the link itself
                    $image_info .= '<a class="lightbox-link button transparent"' . $rel_attribute . 'title="' . $post_title . '" href="' . $thumbnail_src . ' ">' . __('Expand', 'mo_theme') . '</a>';
                    $image_info .= '</div>';
                    $image_info .= '</div>';

                    $after_html .= $image_info;
                }
                $after_html .= '</div>'; // end of image-area
            }
        }
        else {
            if (empty($before_html)) {
                $before_html = '<a title="' . $post_title . '" href="' . $post_link . ' ">';
                $after_html = '</a>' . $after_html;
            }

            if ($wrapper) {
                $wrapper_html = '<div class="image-area">';
                $before_html = $wrapper_html . $before_html;
                if (mo_show_image_info($context) || $show_image_info) {
                    $image_info = '<div class="image-overlay"></div>';
                    $image_info .= '<div class="image-info">';
                    $image_info .= '<div class="post-title"><a title="' . $post_title . '" href="' . $post_link . ' ">' . $post_title . '</a></div>';
                    $image_info .= mo_get_taxonomy_info($taxonomy);
                    $image_info .= '<div class="image-info-buttons">';
                    // point me to the source of the image for lightbox preview
                    $image_info .= '<a class="lightbox-link button transparent"' . $rel_attribute . 'title="' . $post_title . '" href="' . $thumbnail_src . ' ">' . __('Expand', 'mo_theme') . '</a>';
                    $image_info .= '<a class="post-link button transparent" href="' . $post_link . '" title="' . $post_title . '">' . __('Details', 'mo_theme') . '</a>';
                    $image_info .= '</div>';
                    $image_info .= '</div>';

                    $after_html .= $image_info;
                }
                $after_html .= '</div>'; // end of image-area
            }
        }

        $output = $before_html;
        $output .= $thumbnail_element;
        $output .= $after_html;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: show us the php code where you call the image url

Comment: @Vishwa - it seems to be a bit long-winded! I'll update my post in a second

Comment: Interestingly, even if I edit the photo in the admin panel and save it, I still don't get an image. I've even tried updating to the latest version of the theme as well. I'm wondering if I'll need to contact the theme author and get their input

Comment: try var_dump($thumbnail_src) and post the output

Comment: @Vishwa interestingly, that gives: `string(64) "//bodywisegym.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/PT3-1-225x300.jpg"`

Comment: use echo $thumbnail_src in `'<a class="lightbox-link button transparent"' . $rel_attribute . 'title="' . $post_title . '" href="' . $thumbnail_src . ' ">'`

Comment: @Vishwa the problem with that, is that there are loads of other areas that use this code as well. I need to try and fugure out why its wrong :/  (it was working fine on the older server). Maybe I'll try putting the site back to the old WP version, and see if it still has the same issue

Comment: using inspector, can you look for what url you'll get for the image area?

Comment: @Vishwa Mmm it doesn't seem to be an issue with the latest WP version. I just copied live over again, edited the URLs and paths via the "DB Migrate" plugin, and it still has the same issue. http://thebodywisegym.co.uk/ if you want to see the source :)

Comment: when I go to the url given, I can see the images for both     Lewis Fisher and Ryan Anderson

Comment: @Vishwa sorry about that - I copied the wrong URL. Its bodywisegym.co.uk (no "the" at the beginning). The thebodywisegym.co.uk one is on the old server (both are running the same version of WP now)

Comment: im not sure this is the right code. are you sure this is the php code for your homepage?

Comment: @Vishwa yup, it seems to be it (adding debug does print out in that area). I'm talking to the client now about just re-writing it from scratch,. as it seems like the theme is no longer supported now (last reply to anyone was 6 months ago), and a couple of other plugins they used on it are also outdated

Comment: I'm sure it's fixable, anyway I'm not sure that I can tellmore without actually seeing the code myself, sorry about that. outdated doesnt mean that you should abandon it, but yoy may have to take some additional steps yourself to ensure smooth delivery. thats all

Comment: @Vishwa thanks. The customer has agreed to go with a new bespoke site now (WP was a bit overkill for what they needed). Thanks for trying though :) Much appreciated

Comment: glad to be a help anytime..

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [Duplicator – WordPress Migration Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) for migration?. I have also used same plugin used by you for migration but Duplicator is far better then other migration plugins. I think this problem can be resolve by using above plugin.

Comment: thanks, but I can't see how that plugin even works?  It seems to want to create a whole bundle , but I can't see any way to change URLs and paths?